# JavaScript se detiene después de 70 segundos en una funcion

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy dando mantenimiento a un sitio que esta, muy poco optimizado y es extremadamente complicado hacer cambios si descomponerlo, en una parte del codigo se ejecuta esta funcion de JavaScript

```
 function poblarTablaDeRegistros(registros){
        //registrosVisibles = registros;
        
        console.log("procesando: ", registros);
        
        //Vaciar contenedor de registros
        var contenedorDeRegistros = $("#exportTable > tbody").first();
        contenedorDeRegistros.empty();

        $.each(registros,function(index, registro){
            console.log("processing => ", registro);
            //var enReporte = (fichasParaReporte.includes(registro.ID)) ? ""
            var registroHTML = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" disabled onclick="agregarFichaAReporte(this, \'' + registro.ID + '\')"></td>';
            registroHTML += '<td style="display:none;"><input style="visibility: hidden; width: 1%; height: 1%;" value="' + registro.ID + '" name="folio" readonly="">' + registro.ID + '</td>';
            
            registroHTML += (registro.thumb != undefined ? '<td><img style="height: 80px;" src="' + registro.thumb + '"/></td>':'<td></td>');
            
            registroHTML += '<td>' + registro.nombreDeObra + '</td>';
            
            if(registro.AUTOR == ""){
                registro.AUTOR = "Desconocido";
            }
            registroHTML += '<td>' + registro.AUTOR + '</td>';
            registroHTML += '<td>' + registro.MUSEO + '</td>';
            registroHTML += '<td>' + registro.COLECCION + '</td>';
            registroHTML += '<td>' + registro.inventario + '</td>';
            
            registroHTML += '<td><span class="label label-sm label-success">' + ((registro.ID_ESTATUS_REGISTRO == 2) ? "Revisión" : "Validado") + '</span></td>';
            var botonValidar = (registro.ACCIONES.includes('VALIDAR')) ? '<a href="#"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" name="btnValidar"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></a>': "";
            var botonEliminar = (registro.ACCIONES.includes('ELIMINAR')) ? '<a href="#"><button class="btn btn-papelera btn-xs" name="btnPapelera"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></a>': "";
            var botonEditar = (registro.ACCIONES.includes("EDITAR")) ? '<a href="main.php?mr=2&amp;fi=' + registro.ID + '&amp;f=' + registro.ID_FICHA + '&amp;p=' + registro.ID_PERIODO + '"><button class="btn btn-editar btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a>' : ''; 
            var inputFields = '<input type="hidden" value="' + registro.ID + '" name="folio" readonly=""><input type="hidden" value="' + $("#currentUserId").val() + '" name="usuario" readonly=""><input type="hidden" value="' + registro.ID_USUARIO + '" name="usuarioDestino" readonly=""><input type="hidden" value="' + registro.ID_PERIODO + '" name="coleccion" readonly="">';
            registroHTML += '<td><div class="accnstbl"><a href="main.php?mr=25&amp;idr=' + registro.ID + '"><button class="btn btn-editar btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></a>'+ botonEditar + '<form role="form" action="accionRegistro.php" method="post">' + inputFields + botonValidar + botonEliminar + '</form></div></td>';
            
            registroHTML += '<td>' + registro.USUARIO_REGISTRO + '</td>';
            registroHTML += '</tr>';
            contenedorDeRegistros.append(registroHTML);
        });
    }
```

Llegan a la función alrededor de 16,000 registros, pero JavaScript detiene la ejecución cuando transcurren 70 segundos (Lo he cronometrado), error.log no me da mensajes de error por lo que el problema está del lado del cliente
¿Como puedo hacer qué la función no detenga su respectiva ejecución?

Comment: Esto no responde tu pregunta, sino es más bien una crítica al diseño. En realidad no hay humano capaz de procesar 16,000 registros en una sola vista, por tanto no tiene sentido generar una página con tantos datos. Ponle una paginación y muestra los registros de 10  en 20, 20 en 20, etc. Coloca la opción de filtrar para que el usuario pueda localizar los registros de su interés. Y si esto no está hecho para ser procesado por un humano, no uses HTML, entrega JSON o XML desde el backend y que lo procese algún autómata.

Comment: Te comento mi experiencia. Esto pasó el año 2015, y tuve que hacer algo similar eran 5000 registros y para el navegador era imposible renderizarlos, si hacías scroll se freezeaba o en el mejor de los casos demoraba muchos segundos. En mi caso me pasé a silverlight y problema resuelto, podía poner hasta 100.000 filas, pero esta tecnología está muerta. Lo que haría en tu caso es usa una técnica que se llama "Virtual Scroll", donde tu renderizas solo las filas que caben en la pantalla (y unas pocas más a modo de caché) y generas un scroll falso. Cuando haces el scroll vas cargando nuevas filas

Comment: Datatables server side pudiera ser otra opción. Investiga al respecto.